# Box2D web dynamic bodies are not interacting with each other

Tags: javascript, box2d

[image]I have a problem that I have a really hard time solving:

in the image you can see the debug view of my scene. these two active dynamic bodies are not pushing each other away!
I have not set any collision bits in the scene, so everything should be colliding with each other normally...

This problem does not occur when dynamic bodies hit static bodies.
Has anyone had this problem before, I have no idea what setting i did wrong for dynamic bodies to just ignore each other like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i think i found the problem...
i was using b2Body.GetPosition() every frame to update the image that goes with the body.
and because in JS every object is passed as reference i was overwriting Box2Ds position when scaling back to pixels!